# BASH - using a for loop to loop over an array and create a file from the loop body

Tags: arrays, bash, file, loops, cat

It;s only outputting the final loop body because of the way my loop is set up, the variable var's final result will be the final element in my array. How would I loop through the body and add all of the results of my array to the .sql file?

Comment: please include your code as text, not an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "CREATE TABLE $NameOfTable (" > "$NameOfSqlFile.sql"
for i in "${ColumnArray[@]}"
do
echo "$i,"
done >> "$NameOfSqlFile.sql"
echo ")" >> "$NameOfSqlFile.sql"
```

Comment: That would create an sql text file for each element in my array. I want one text file to hold the loop results of my array

Comment: @user3544582: I've updated my answer--please check again.

Comment: Beautiful! If you remove the EOF at the end of where your wrote echo, it works!